# Does the [tag:avengers-vs-x-men] tag refer to the cross-over comics, or the contest?

Tags: support, tags, contest

It seems that most of the questions being asked in response to the comic are being tagged as [avengers-vs-x-men](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-vs-x-men), even though most of those questions don't seem relevant to the cross-over comic of that title (for example, [questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14352/when-did-icemans-power-expand) [about](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14302/what-ever-happened-to-falcon) [specific](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14292/has-a-super-villain-ever-been-an-avenger) [individuals](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14247/what-are-the-upper-limits-of-cyclops-optic-blast)).

Should the tag be used for all questions under the contest, or only for those questions directly relating to the cross-over comics of that same title?

Whichever way we decide, the wording of the [rules](http://avx.stackshowdown.com/rules) may need to clarify this.  My interpretation of the rules is that any combination of [x-men](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men), [avengers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers), and [avengers-vs-x-men](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-vs-x-men) qualifies a question (although [avengers-vs-x-men](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-vs-x-men) without either of the other two are only valid for the grand-prize drawing).  Is this correct?  If so, maybe we should tell people they shouldn't add [avengers-vs-x-men](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-vs-x-men) unless they're talking about the cross-over.

Comment: The avengers-vs-x-men tag should be on questions only about the mini-series, NOT the event. Questions tagged with just Avengers or X-Men are eligible, they do not have to be paired with avengers-vs-x-men

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag [avengers-vs-x-men](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-vs-x-men) means that the question relates to the [*Avengers vs. X-Men*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers_vs._X-Men) comic book series.

Do not use [avengers-vs-x-men](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-vs-x-men) to indicate that a question was asked as part of the contest. Tags classify questions according to their subject, nor according to their context. That a question was asked during the contest period is irrelevant to its classification.

A question is part of the contest if it has any of the three tags [avengers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers), [x-men](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men) or [avengers-vs-x-men](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-vs-x-men). If it's only about *X-Men* or only about *Avengers*, it must not have the tag [avengers-vs-x-men](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-vs-x-men).

Comment: This is correct...

Answer (score 1):

> My interpretation of the rules is that any combination of [x-men](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men), [avengers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers), and [avengers-vs-x-men](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-vs-x-men) qualifies a question (although [avengers-vs-x-men](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-vs-x-men) without either of the other two are only valid for the grand-prize drawing).  Is this correct?

Yes, that is correct.  In this case, you should retag the question so it has useful tags.  This contest will draw in many new users who aren't familiar with the specifics of how tags should be used here, so we as a community need to be extra-vigilant to edit questions to make them a proper fit here.

Comment: That's what I had been doing, but I noticed that some of our high-rep users were going through and adding the [tag:avengers-vs-x-men] to questions that didn't seem relevant, so I thought I'd double check.